# JSoup returning incomplete HTML document

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to fetch a html doc using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) but it returns incomplete HTML.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923");
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: what do you expect? what do you get instead?

Comment: I am expecting start page of html should has <html> but the document fetched has a start element <tr> .However, the document ends correctly with </body></html> which is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum size of the document needs to be extended.  By default it sets the max limit to 1MB.  By setting it to 0 it will have an unlimited size.

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(String url);
connection.maxBodySize(0);
Document doc = connection.get();
```

See the Jsoup documentation: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#maxBodySize(int)